# How to remove the time part from a column that has a date type in SSRS 2008?

Tags: datetime, ssrs-2008, datetime-format

I am new to SSRS environment. I have created a report that fetches data from a table.

Although the data contains only date, SSRS appends "12:00:00 AM" to
the values.
I want to remove the "!2:00:00 AM" without having to convert the date into string.

I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: format as shortdatetime or specify format via mm/dd/yyyy in expression see link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query in your date column.
select CONVERT(varchar(10),date_column ,120) as ReportDate

This would give the below output

```
ReportDate
2014-09-29
```